# How to proper configurate mod_proxy_uwsgi

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I got uwsgi running behind nginx. All is working fine, but I want to change from nginx to Apache2 with mod_proxy_uwsgi.

I cannot get a connection (access and error.log of appache are blank)

My uwsgi.ini is:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = umap
gid = users
chdir           = /srv/umap/
module          = umap.wsgi
home            = /srv/umap/venv
env = UMAP_SETTINGS=/srv/umap/local.py
master          = true
processes       = 4
socket          = /srv/umap/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
stats           = /srv/umap/stats.sock
vacuum          = true
plugins         = python3
```

my nginx-config

```
upstream umap {
    server unix:///srv/umap/uwsgi.sock;
}
server {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    listen      8001;
    listen   [::]:8001;
    server_name 192.168.127.25;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 5M;   # adjust to taste
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  umap;
        include     /srv/umap/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

How is the right code for the pass to the proxy?

```
<VirtualHost *:8002>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/8002error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/8002access.log combined
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / unix:/srv/umap/uwsgi.sock|uwsgi://uwsgi-uds-app1/
    ProxyVia On
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```